# Can we create a Dictionary with Generic?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

In Stanford's class(see the picture 1), the professor initialized a Dictionary like this:

```
var a = Dictionary<String: Int>()
```

[image: picture 1]

But it cannot work in my computer(see the picture 2), is there something wrong?

[image: picture 2]

Comment: Please post code, not pictures of code. Nobody wants to waste their typing typing out what it shows.

Comment: Don't you see I already post my code there?

Comment: I intended that to be justification of the "no pictures of code" policy in general, not specific to this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dictionary` is a generic struct, whose generic type parameters can be defined in the same way as any other generic struct, using a comma separated list in angle brackets:

```
let a = Dictionary<String, Int>()
```

There's also a special syntactic sugar that's specific to dictionaries, that let you express the same as above as:

```
let a = [String: Int]()
```

Mixing the two together as in `Dictionary<String: Int>` is invalid.